# Fixed Button in Scroll View

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I develop an activity with Navigation Drawer, and I want to fix a button on the screen, verticaly at the middle, and horizontaly at the left, but I don't know what to do that and the search around Internet do not complete my work... Have you an idea ?

This is my layout XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawerLayoutArticleDetail"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/snow" 
>
<ScrollView 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" >

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/featuredImg"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp" 
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true">
    </ImageView> 

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/img_full_screen"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/featuredImg"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/featuredImg"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_action_full_screen"/>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/img_count"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:minWidth="15sp"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@null"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/img_full_screen"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/img_full_screen"
        android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="4dp"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_square"/>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/city_name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_below="@+id/featuredImg" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/city_name"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="3dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/defaultColor"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/summary_article"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/article_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/summary_article"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:padding="5dp" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/content_article"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/article_date"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#00000c" >
    </WebView>

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewDrawerArticleDetail"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:divider="@color/snow"
    android:dividerHeight="5dp"
    android:background="@color/snow" 
    android:padding="10dp"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: use a FrameLayout with a ScrollView and a Button as child views